# Rendering current view with error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render the same view but with the error messages when they fail to post a comment.

Comments.controllers

```
def create
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @comment = @project.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.user_id = current_user.id
       if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      @projectboard_items = []
      flash[:danger] = "Sorry! your comment was not created"
      render @project #<----- replace this line
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under the else put this

format.html { redirect_to new_comment_path, notice: 'Sorry! your comment was not created.' }

Comment: so yes and no it its the behaviour I want but my error messages are not being displayed there, for some reason... they only get displayed when I render a view but when I do that the comment feed dissapears